# How can I use price_get with xmlrpc?

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

I am trying to execute a method on an odoo12 server using the odoo_rpc_client.

the function I use is the following:

`priceEntity = odooClient.execute('product.pricelist', 'price_get', ([1], 5591, 1), {})`

The error output is: unhashable type: 'list': 'Traceback (most recent call last)

tks

Comment: You need to show more code and an error message.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `(1, 5591, 1)` because the method signature is `def price_get(self, prod_id, qty, partner=None)` and i guess `prod_id` means one ID not a list of IDs. The docstring says mono product, too: `Multi pricelist, mono product - returns price per pricelist `